# Reencoding MXF (OP-1a) XDCAM HD422 MPEG into something useful

Tags: vlc-media-player, ffmpeg, mpeg, adobe-after-effects

I am a bit desperate at this point. I have a video file in the MXF container format. MediaInfo identifies it as MXF (OP-1a) XDCAM HD422 and says the Video Stream is plain MPEG. I want to edit the video using AfterEffects CS4, and the format seems to be supported if I read [this site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AfterEffects/9.0/WSB108BC99-A69B-46c4-86D3-2192805C2AF8a.html) correctly.

Unfortunately, when I try to import the file, I am told that AfterEffects does not support that format. The only software I have been able to read this file correctly with was VLC, and the pre-alpha VLMC. The former is a player only however, and the latter exports video fine, but removes the audio in the process, even though the audio track is in the timeline, not muted, and plays fine in the source video in VLMC (not in the timeline... it plays only video there).

Does somebody know how I can get this file into After Effects (or some more common format) using freeware or After Effects? I am not willing to buy another converter for that file. Your help is greatly appreciated.

I am on OS X, but I also have Windows 7 at hand, and I am willing to build stuff from Source or install through MacPorts if that helps. I would even setup a VirtualBox with an Ubuntu if I have to, but I really don't hope I do to read a video file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have MacPorts, I'd install [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) through either [`ffmpeg-devel`](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/multimedia/ffmpeg-devel/Portfile) or `ffmpeg`. Note that the normal `ffmpeg` port is really outdated, your mileage may vary.

```
sudo port install ffmpeg-devel
```

Then, using this, convert the video to an intermediate codec like Apple [ProRes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProRes_422):

```
ffmpeg -i file.mxf -vcodec prores -acodec pcm_s16le out.mov
```

This will ensure that your file is easy to process, as intermediate codecs can be read faster by NLE's, and that your file is compatible with Apple Pro applications like Final Cut, as well as other QuickTime applications. Adobe Premiere and After Effects should also be able to read it, as long as you keep your workflow on the Mac.

Comment: You were right, I needed ffmpeg-devel. But then I worked, and AfterEffects reads prores without a problem - thank you!